# javascript function issue with template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have just bought a template and now I found out that a function of one of the pages is not working

As you can see in this page:

http://ava-themes.com/HTML/Brander/Brander/blog-masonry-full-width.html

if you keep clicking on filter buttons, the width of the column becomes more and more small, till the columns become really horrible

This is the javascript function that has the bug, I'm not able to find the problem...

```
//Masonery
$(window).load(function() {
    $(function() {

        $.Isotope.prototype._getCenteredMasonryColumns = function() {
            this.width = this.element.width();
            var parentWidth = this.element.parent().width();
            // i.e. options.masonry && options.masonry.columnWidth
            var colW = this.options.masonry && this.options.masonry.columnWidth ||
            // or use the size of the first item
            this.$filteredAtoms.outerWidth(true) ||
            // if there's no items, use size of container
            parentWidth;
            var cols = Math.floor(parentWidth / colW);
            cols = Math.max(cols, 1);
            // i.e. this.masonry.cols = ....
            this.masonry.cols = cols;
            // i.e. this.masonry.columnWidth = ...
            this.masonry.columnWidth = colW;
        };

        $.Isotope.prototype._masonryReset = function() {
            // layout-specific props
            this.masonry = {};
            // FIXME shouldn't have to call this again
            this._getCenteredMasonryColumns();
            var i = this.masonry.cols;
            this.masonry.colYs = [];
            while (i--) {
                this.masonry.colYs.push(0);
            }
        };

        $.Isotope.prototype._masonryResizeChanged = function() {
            var prevColCount = this.masonry.cols;
            // get updated colCount
            this._getCenteredMasonryColumns();
            return (this.masonry.cols !== prevColCount);
        };

        $.Isotope.prototype._masonryGetContainerSize = function() {
            var unusedCols = 0,
                i = this.masonry.cols;
            // count unused columns
            while (--i) {
                if (this.masonry.colYs[i] !== 0) {
                    break;
                }
                unusedCols++;
            }
            return {
                height: Math.max.apply(Math, this.masonry.colYs),
                // fit container to columns that have been used;
                width: (this.masonry.cols - unusedCols) * this.masonry.columnWidth
            };
        };


        var $container = $('#container'),
            $body = $('body'),
            colW = 1,
            columns = null;

        $container.isotope({
            // disable window resizing
            resizable: false,
            masonry: {
                columnWidth: colW
            }
        });

        //FILTERING
        $('#filters a').click(function() {
            var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
            $container.isotope({
                filter: selector
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
});
///End masonery
```

Comment: Is anybody to understand where is the bug? I'm trying to understand, but I'm javascript beginner...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure as to what is causing the width of `#container` to shrink. Looks like the calculation done here is wrong.

Try debugging this method `$.Isotope.prototype._masonryGetContainerSize`

What I can suggest as a good temporary fix for now is to set the `width` of `#container` in style.css to `100% !important`. That seems to do the job.

Comment: unfortunately setting #container{
 width:100% !important;
} messes up the responsive design :(